# looping tableview cell label text from an array

Tags: arrays, uitableview, swift3, tableview

I have an array :

```
let BRIArray = ["ATM BRI", "Internet Banking BRI"]
```

and then I count it at cellForRowAt:

```
let BRIArrayCount = BRIArray.count
```

and then I loop it :

```
for i in 0 ..< BRIArrayCount {
                print (i) //i will increment up one with each iteration of the for loop
                cell.lblBankPayment.text = "\(BRIArray[i])"
                print("BRIArray: \(BRIArray[i])")
            }
```

But the result just get last string and loop it like image below:
[image]

How to correct the loop inside cellForRowAt to show all array string in cell label text?

Answer (score 2):

No need to use loop
instead of loop
just use

cell.lblBankPayment.text = "(BRIArray[indexPath.row])"

if you want all the text in single label concat string in loop then set it

let str = "(str)(" ")(BRIArray[index])"

Comment: if i set like this cell.lblBankPayment!.text = BRIArray[indexPath.row], sometimes it got fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: than you can use if statement check ex if BRIArray.count <= indexPath.row{
cell.lblBankPayment.text = "(BRIArray[indexPath.row])"
}